# Nginx with redmine as sub uri doesn't work

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, redmine, thin

I installed redmine with thin and nginx on my raspberry pi. I am able to access my redmine installation using `http://raspberrypi/`. However I want it to be `http://raspberrypi/redmine`.

My current (working) nginx site config looks like this:

```
upstream redmine {
  server unix:/var/run/thin/redmine.0.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name raspberrypi;
  root /usr/share/redmine/public;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://redmine/;
  }
}
```

When I change the location line to `location /redmine {` I can access redmine using `http://raspberrypi/redmine` but all links are pointing to `http://raspberrypi/` without "redmine" appended and are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line at the bottom of your `config/environment.rb`

```
Redmine::Utils::relative_url_root = "/redmine"
```

Start the thin server with `--prefix /redmine`, in my case:

```
thin start --prefix "/redmine" -s1 --socket /tmp/thin.sock
```

Change your nginx configuration to:

```
location /redmine {
   proxy_pass http://redmine/redmine;
}
```

Also look at the [documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI).

Comment: Thank's for your reply, unfortunately it isn't working (I tried both lines from the wiki). Do I have to change anything else in the nginx config?

Comment: Thank you!! That works! I've spent so many hours on this today and you saved the day ;).

Answer (score 0):

Change the following lines at the bottom of your "/var/www/redmine/config" /environment.rb

change ::

```
# Initialize the Rails application
Rails.application.initialize!
```

to::

```
RedmineApp::Application.routes.default_scope = "/redmine" 
# Initialize the Rails application
Rails.application.initialize!
```

URL : http://adresse_ip/redmine